# R: how to plot a 3D interactive plot with confidence intervals?

Tags: r, data-visualization, plot3d

```
library(plot3D)
data(iris)
x <- sep.l <- iris$Sepal.Length
y <- pet.l <- iris$Petal.Length
z <- sep.w <- iris$Sepal.Width
CI <- list(z = matrix(nrow = length(x),
                      data = rep(0.1, 2*length(x))))
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
scatter3D(x, y, z, phi = 0, bty = "g", col = gg.col(100), 
          pch = 18, CI = CI)
```

Running the above code gives me a scatter plot, but I can't seem to interact with it.

[image]

I know that the `plot3d` function from `rgl` package does have interactive 3D plots, but I didn't see an option to add confidence intervals.

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
plot3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000))
```

Is there a way to create an interactive 3D plot with CIs?

Comment: The `scatter3d` function is not part of pkg:`rgl`. It's not supposed to be an interactive plot. Furthermore the scatterplot3d package is not being used here so am removing that tag.

Comment: I think `plot3Drgl` uses the `rgl` package.  Use function `scatter3Drgl` instead of `scatter3D`.

Comment: @IRTFM Yes, but I can't seem to find a function/package that does both: i.e., interactive and can plot confidence intervals. I've found functions that only do one or the other. Or so it seems.

Comment: CI's are typically plotted in base graphics with the `arrow` functon. There is an arrow in rgl.

Comment: I see CIs in `scatter3Drgl`.